# ALTERNATIVE QUERY "LIKE" MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB and made several queries to find some data in the field

Query :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN alamat.alamat_prins LIKE '%Aceh%' THEN 1 END
    ) AS 'id-ac'
FROM
    kont_uji_rutin AS UjiRutin 
    LEFT JOIN alamat ON UjiRutin.id_prins = alamat.id_prins 
WHERE
    UjiRutin.tgl_tri BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
```

Using the LIKE query is the slowest way to do full text matching on what I have. Are there alternative queries to look up data in the field provided that it has the word "Aceh"?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Google *mariadb fulltext search*

Comment: One possible speedup:  `LEFT JOIN` --> `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the comparison to the `WHERE` clause and dispense with the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'id_ac'
FROM kont_uji_rutin ur JOIN
     alamat a
     ON ur.id_prins = a.id_prins 
WHERE ur.tgl_tri BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' AND
      a.alamat_prins LIKE '%Aceh%';
```

This will not have a big impact on performance.  Indexes on:

- `kont_uji_rutin(tgl_tri, id_prins)`
- `alamat(id_prins, alamat_prins)`

are worth trying (they cover the query which might have a performance benefit).

Ultimately, though, the problem is the wildcard at the beginning of the pattern.  This prevents the use of an index.  You might consider a full-text index on `alamat(alamat_prins)`.  That should speed the query, if the full text functionality meets your needs.